# iOS: How to prevent table from updating if row is currently being swiped?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table that is being populated by a Firebase database. The user can swipe each row left and right, which causes the row to disappear. This is coming from this library: https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell

If I'm in the middle of swiping a row and the table updates with new data, my swipe gesture resets and the row that I was swiping gets pushed down.

Is there a way to prevent updates on the table while one of the rows is currently being interacted with?

Comment: How the swiping functionality has been achieved? are you using a library?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that info. Updated the question: https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell

Comment: Another question, after getting new data, are you calling `tableView.reloadData()` ?

Comment: Correct... it is being called. Perhaps it is unavoidable?

Comment: Was my answer useful? or should I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the reason of the issue is that you are -somehow- calling `tableView.reloadData()` after getting new data (which sounds ok), the updating of the table view causes to edit the number of its rows which leads to push the current swiped cell.

The solution is to check if there is a cell swiping currently happening to prevent the calling of `tableView.reloadData()`, this should be done after the swiping finished. Fortunately, after checking the used [MCSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell) library, I found how to check such a functionality, by conforming to [`MCSwipeTableViewCellDelegate`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MCSwipeTableViewCell/1.1.0/Protocols/MCSwipeTableViewCellDelegate.html) as follows:

- Implement `swipeTableViewCellDidStartSwiping:` to prevent `tableView.reloadData()`.
- Implement `swipeTableViewCell:didEndSwipingSwipingWithState:mode:` to make sure that the swiping ended and then calling `tableView.reloadData()`.

Of course the logic of how you will do the checking is up to you, but -hopefully- this guides you to solve the issue.

Hope this helped.